# THREE Raycaster not getting userData

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I am using this code to get intersects and I'm getting the correct objects but the userData:{} is empty.

```
var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children[8].children, true);
```

userData has 2 properties and they are not getting moved to intersects variable instead the userData under intersects is empty. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, when I was assigning the parameters to userData, I was doing it to the group object rather than the mesh.

Answer (score 2):

`userData` or other `Object3D` properties are not available in the array of intersections. However, you can retrieve the 3D object from an intersection object like so:

```
if ( intersects.length > 0 ) console.log( intersects[ 0 ].object.userData );
```

This will log the `userData` property for the first intersection.

Comment: I tried that it doesn't work, the problem seems to be before the if statement, intersects[].object.userData is empty

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue with a live example? https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/